# Can I set Eclipse to only emit errors, warnings, etc. for the current project?

Tags: eclipse, customization

I want to be able to ignore warnings in other projects in my workspace when I'm concentrating on my current project. I looked through Window | Preferences and saw no such option. Eclipse obviously *knows* which project is current, because when I mash F11 it runs (or tries to).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the Problems view, click the little triangle thinggie on the right, and select **Show** -> **Errors/Warnings on selection**. Then it will show the errors from the currently selected project/file, etc.

[image: Triangle Thing]

Answer (score 3):

You can either Close Project all other projects, you can set a filter on the Problems View to only show errors for the current project, or use Mylin to limit the scope of what you are currently seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded Eclipse (Helios) to the latest version of the SDK and LogCat shows my current application automagically.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Working Sets` to put projects into logical groups.